# what is the value of z/w?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

Let $|w|=3$ come out of the origin and and let $|z|=2$ and also come out of the origin.  Both lines are in the second quadrant and form an angle of $\frac{\pi}{3}$ degrees. What is the value of $\frac z w$?

[image]

Comment: Do you know what happens to the moduli when you multiply or divide complex numbers?  What happens to the arguments?  Try to find out and then it will be easy.

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{z}{w}=\frac{2}{3}e^{\frac{\pi i}{3}}$  The magnitude is obvious, while the angle is simply the difference in angle between them.

Comment: what is the real part of that solution? I tried 1/3, but it was wrong.  What am I missing?

Comment: $e^\frac{\pi i}{3}=cos(\frac{\pi i}{3})+isin(\frac{\pi i}{3})$, so $x+iy=\frac{1}{3}+i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$.  Why do you think it's wrong?

Comment: Your diagram has $|z|\gt |w|$.  Is it possible you made a mistake in the original statement?

Answer (score 1):

I completely agree with Herb Steinberg's answer, but would like to focus on why the OP had trouble with this question.  Math students are taught how to attack problems like this one in a textbook on complex analysis.  Math students normally defer studying complex analysis until they have studied both calculus and real analysis.

To the OP, and others in a similar situation:  it is not a good idea to try to "re-invent the wheel", meaning don't try to solve this (or similar problems) on your own.  Instead, get a complex analysis textbook.

Further, it is not a good idea to tackle subjects out of order.  Get grounded in calculus and real analysis before tackling complex analysis.

Comment: You are right about complex analysis.  However the arithmetic of complex numbers should be taught as part of elementary algebra,

Comment: @herbsteinberg "...however the arithmetic...".  With respect to $z+w$ or $z\times w$, I agree.  However, I think that $z/w$ is pushing it, and I am not surprised that a complex analysis newbie reacted to a $z/w$ problem with a mathSE query.

Comment: I presume any introduction to complex arithymetic would include the notion of complex conjugate and that the product of a complex number and its conjugate is real.  Therefore $\frac{z}{w}=\frac{z\bar{w}}{w\bar{w}}$.

Comment: @herbsteinberg "I presume any ...".  Agreed.  If I was presented with that formula for $z/w,$ I would have to do some work (i.e. from scratch) to verify it.  Instead, I am going through Bruce Palka's "Intro to Complex Function Theory", which introduces the formula early in chapter 1.  By using a book instead of working from scratch, there is an **overall solidity** to my complex analysis intuition.  Hence, I still maintain that "$z/w$ is pushing it."

Comment: If you are starting from scratch from a textbook, your point may be valid.  My first encounter with complex numbers was in a high school algebra course, so the basics  (addition, etc., complex conjugates) would be part of the curriculum.  This was long before complex function theory - an advanced college level course.